# justify-content space between

Tags: html, css

I'm working with formatting some divs with a flex box and thought that justify-content: space-between is the best way to do it. But, I'm running into an issue when the browser resolution changes the items become misaligned. For example if I shrink the browser size the items will wrap onto the next line which is fine since I have flex-wrap: wrap, but on the new line that is created the contents are spread between. Is it possible to remove the justify-content every time the items wrap? Sorry for the poor explanation, I'll provide a jsfiddle. Change the fiddle to 483px and the items will wrap and be placed on the next line, but instead of space between I want the items to be placed next to each other.

http://jsfiddle.net/xut5cqhw/46/

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
    width: 40%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: black;
}

.content {
    height: 50px;
    width:  50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

<div class = "container">
  <div class="content">
  </div>
    <div class="content">
  </div>
    <div class="content">
  </div>
    <div class="content">
  </div>
    <div class="content">
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: You could do a min-width in percentage and then flex-grow: 1 on the children, that would allow any wrapped elements to fill the entire section, though that will make the justify-content: space-between basically null.

Comment: grid will be fully efficient here i believe : http://jsfiddle.net/5mtunq94/ (flex-wrap has no effect with grid, i forgot to remove it)